# My tomcat is blue after I configure HTTPS

Tags: tomcat, https, server

I don't know why my tomcat is blue, after I config the https, not like other website, its a lock icon.

In the safira, my link is with a blue tomcat, why?:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My link is: https://www.aijiwu123.xyz/transaction/userAction/doLogin

But in others website, the normal https website, it should be like this, have a lock icon:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why my link do not have the lock icon?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your certificate is not signed by any certificate authority that would be trusted by the server. Opening the site myself results in the following error:

```
www.aijiwu123.xyz uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

If you want to get "the lock icon" and trusted connection, you need to either buy a certificate for your domain, or use Let's Encrypt to get trusted certificate for free.